# Existe um guia (curto, se possível) sobre como escolher bem o título da pergunta?

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Olhando qualquer página, vemos MUITAS perguntas com títulos insignificantes, ou (acho que a maioria) que dizem o que o usuário está fazendo, não seu problema. Não vou nem colocar referências, basta olhar a primeira página de perguntas.

Está no ponto em que dá vontade de votar uma pergunta simplesmente pelo fato de ter um bom título.

É difícil editar, pois pra isso você precisa entender muito bem a pergunta e o assunto. Leva tempo, mesmo quando você tem certeza que o título não está bom.

Existe um guia legal que ensine a criar títulos, que a gente possa postar em comentário, para, pelo menos, tentar conscientizar?

Comment: Acho esse tipo de coisa de muita importância, porque o fato de termos muitos usuários novatos É BOM - a longo prazo, e melhor se soubermos acomodar isso. Mesmo isso se reflete, no momento, em baixa qualidade.

Comment: Não sei se existe mas concordo que deveria. E concordo também que não é nada simples dar títulos às perguntas dos outros.

Comment: O título(as tags também) deveria refletir qual é o problema, as vezes OP não tem noção do problema que está enfrentando, aí vai de um usuário experiente sacar a dúvida dele, confirmar e adicionar um título bacana, veja o exemplo dessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88747/deve-se-usar-break-em-for), olha a diferença que faz o título.

Comment: Relacionado: [Edição de título para facilitar as buscas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/91) 
[Devo editar o título de uma pergunta a fim de torná-la mais objetiva?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2376/91) 
[Dúvida em editar um título para algo mais apropriado e técnico](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2679/91)

Comment: @rray Acho tags mais simples - e sua correção mais sistemática. Quanto a depender do caminho que a resposta leva, concordo, mas me referia antes mais aos títulos bem abaixo desse nível... aqueles que, independente do que aconteça, estão ruins.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu tinha pensado, inicialmente, em escrever um guia.. mas não  ficará bom, então faria em resposta como wiki.

Comment: Exemplo de título que não diz nada: [Ajuda com retorno de função!](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88949/ajuda-com-retorno-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: @JorgeB. eu entendo o título dessa pergunta como, `return void` xD

Comment: foi esse que iniciou meu movimento... porque entrei na pergunta e não soube colocar um melhor. Mas em sua defesa, não é especialmente pior que a média.

Comment: Eu ia mesmo postar isso @JorgeB.

Comment: Pior que nesse caso, nós não temos como ajudar a melhorar

Comment: Exato... por isso fui atrás de um tutorial de títulos (títorial?)

Comment: Tem só dois problemas. O novato não é de fato incentivado a aprender fazer o melhor no site. E é muito comum ele não ter condições de fazer melhor. Ele tem dificuldade de expressar seu problema. Ele não sabe qual é o problema, ou quando sabe, não consegue descrevê-lo. Tem casos que os experientes podem ajudar, tem casos que nem isto é possível. O que precisa arrumar mais são os títulos: "Me ajuda aí". Depois os "dúvida com asp".

Comment: @RSinohara * Bah dum Tiss *

Comment: @RSinohara Dei +1 pela tentativa falhada de piada :P ^^^^

Comment: Pergunta: a seção de ajuda é facilmente editável? Especificamente, existe um privilégio que permite mexer nelas?

Comment: @JorgeB. inclusive porque o problema, me parece olhando por cima, não está no retorno :) "Vou tomar uma aspirina pra ver se passa a dor que estou sentindo porque perdi a perna" :)

Comment: @bigown Exatamente... o que eu queria era deixar um comentário pronto, com algo do tipo "O título da sua pergunta é a única coisa que a maioria dos usuários vê. Com um bom título, mais pessoas irão acessar sua pergunta. No formato atual, seu título não [descreve seu problema/trás informação nenhuma/parece que um gato passou no teclado]. talvez isso possa ajudar {link para um títorial}"

Comment: @bigown não tem nada a ver no máximo punha Ajuda com foreach ou assim ;)

Comment: @RSinohara insistindo no títorial ahahahahah

Comment: @JorgeB. Aí o indivíduo bota o título: 'Aspirina ou Tylenol?'

Comment: Ainda melhor que o de antes! Talvez.

Comment: @RSinohara [parece que um gato passou no teclado] é perfeito.

Comment: @RSinohara eu acho bom fazer isto, ainda que na maioria dos casos não vai ajudar. Existe a preguiça, a pessoa não está interessada no objetivo do site, só no dele. E existe a incapacidade dele fazer melhor. O que é outro problema que eu acho que não tem como resolver. O que podemos tentar fazer é descobrir o que ele quer de fato e melhorar o título. Se não dá, provavelmente a pergunta deve ser fechada. E muita gente não lê esses *links* que a gente passa*. Outro postaram e nunca mais voltaram no site. Tem que lembrar dessas coisas.

Comment: @bigown Eu tenho realmente notado isso: `a pessoa não está interessada no objetivo do site, só no dele.`

Comment: @bigown Concordo. Mas tenho uma tendência de fazer minha parte... Se está ruim, penso em como melhorar e, se der, tento aplicar. Mas não discordo que o _hit rate_ vai ser baixo se não for nulo. Mas a diferença, pra mim, é um site que fornece as dicas (que as pessoas não seguem) Vs um site que não as fornece. O resultado pode ser igual, mas eu me sinto melhor.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno isso que é interessante... voltar pra marcar resposta, corrigir a pergunta, vá lá, pode ser exigir demais. Mas o título da pergunta... isso não é só pro site... é pelo AP que, afinal, levou um tempo pra fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Um dos problemas é que o o sujeito não quer aprender programar. Ele só quer saber o que fazer com o molho de tomate dele que está ruim depois dele ter colocado 1kg de açúcar porque disseram que tinha que por açúcar. Então ficamos enxugando gelo. Mas o que quero dizer é que não temos muito o que fazer a não ser fazer o possível pra arrumar o que está errado, e tentar mostrar p/ a pessoa o que e porque ele deve melhorar o título.

Comment: @RSinohara sim, tem que fazer, não estou dizendo que não tem.

Comment: Ai mais um exemplo: [Java - Função Enter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88968/java-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-enter)

Comment: Hoje ta complicado, deve ser pq é sexta rs

Comment: Ah, tem muitos. Sério, dá vontade de dar up em pergunta que tem título bom mesmo. Mas às vezes abre a pergunta e passa :)

Comment: Alguém falou nas *tags*, acho elas muito importantes também, talvez mais que o título. Tanto a falta de algumas importantes, como o uso de *tags* inadequadas. Tipo usar [tag:visual-studio] em algo que ele só está usando o VS para fazer o código, mas o problema não está no VS. Ou [tag:interface] quando se está falando de GUI. Ou [tag:web] só porque a aplicação é web. Mas a que eu gosto é da [tag:princípios-de-programação] que a última vez que eu vi só uma pergunta tem a ver com o tema. Mas eu gosto dela porque é *honeypot* pra perguntar :)

Comment: Eu acho - sem base, só acho - que as tags são mais sistematicamente corrigidas (pois não deixam dúvidas, quem entende sabe se está com tag a mais ou faltando). Não acontece isso?

Comment: O ruim de alguém mais experiente de editar um título, e muda-lo para um outro titulo mais conciso com o que o OP quis passar, é que muitas pessoas com a mesma dúvida provavelmente não procurariam por desta forma, e sim da forma original, tipo: "Como enviar dados sem mudar de página" para: "Como enviar dados de forma assíncrona", i.e um usuário que está com a mesma dúvida dificilmente procuraria da forma para que foi modificada, apesar de ser mais conciso/reduzido e técnico, não ajudaria. Minha opinião..

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus  Exato. Às vezes - muitas vezes - não conseguimos anterar por não ter certeza sair da intenção original do título. Daí a ideia de criar um guia e pedir ao AP para melhorar o título.