# Como escolher um bom título?

Tags: debate, título

Na [discussão "existe um guia para escolher o título](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4385/26643), ficamos de montar um guia sobre [como escolher um bom título](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/26643), especificamente para podermos 'linkar' como comentário nas perguntas cujo título deixa a desejar.

Não me julgando especialista no assunto, quero recolher aqui conselhos, dicas, e, se possível, regras para bons títulos.

Eventualmente vou compilar o que tivemos em um guia curto para poder postar em perguntas e, quem sabe, ajudar uma parcela dos usuário com isso.

Comment: Primeira dúvida minha é: todo título deve ser uma pergunta? Ou pelo menos a grandíssima maioria?

Comment: Se estamos num site de Q&A acho que cada título deveria ser uma pergunta sim.

Comment: Consegui várias dicas aqui:[SOen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306999/1387277). Já dá pra começar.

Comment: @JorgeB.: isso já foi discutido por gente experiente [citation needed] e o consenso é "não importa se tem interrogação ou não, importa que descreva o problema de maneira sucinta"

Comment: @brasofilo eu só disse o que eu acho. Nem eu faço sempre pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB., no problem... como editor me oriento por isso, tento extrair o melhor título sem importar se constitui uma pergunta ou não...

Answer (score 4):

Se fizermos uma compilação de [***How do I write a good title?***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) e colocarmos nossos temperos lusoparlantes teremos uma resposta canônica para esta questão.

Só escrevo esta resposta para registrar algo que descobri hoje trabalhando com compra e venda (nunca fiz, sempre fui de produção). Mais do que mostrar documentos, detalhes, referências, o importante é puxar a atenção dizendo *"isto é bom para você porque tal e tal";* uma vez entendido isso, a parte dos detalhes fica bem mais fácil.

Experimentando essa tese, modifiquei o [título](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/89756/revisions) para dar o exemplo e fiz o seguinte comentário, achei o *feedback* bem bom:


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Sim, o pessoal do SOen postou bastante material além do que você mencionou, assim que tiver um tempo vou dar uma olhada e trazer aqui o mais importante.[Guide for titles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306999/1387277)

Comment: Muito bom isto `Write your question first, then the title.`! Normalmente, para consertar um título ruim é só repassar o texto que às vezes tem um título prontinho ali dentro.

Comment: @brasofilo tentei e não deu certo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89843/como-preencher-uma-tabela-elemento-table-do-html-a-partir-de-um-list-c-asp-ne?noredirect=1#comment181777_89843 :D Já falei bastante sobre isto, não preciso ficar repetindo.

Comment: @bigown: jejeje, em toda tese sempre tem uma alma caridosa pra desmontá-la sem piedade