# Que tal um alerta para perguntas em outro idiomas?

Tags: novo-recurso

Existe no sistema como identificar (a partir de expressões regulares, se entendi bem) se a pergunta redigida está no idioma esperado pela comunidade. Por exemplo, ao criar uma pergunta em português no SOen temos isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao tentar fazer uma pergunta em inglês no SOpt temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dada a [resposta do g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3306) no SOes, no SOen é utilizado expressões regulares com palavras típicas daquele idioma. Sendo assim, por que não ativamos também este recurso no SOpt a fim de reduzir as publicações em inglês?

**Nota:** Se ativado, o filtro será aplicado tanto em perguntas quanto em respostas e leva em consideração inclusive trechos de código (mas parece levar em consideração a densidade de termos em outro idioma em relação a publicação - isto é, um texto em português com variáveis em inglês provavelmente não farão ativar o filtro), mas ainda estará suscetível a falsos negativos:

- [False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325865/1452488)

Em poucas horas hoje, dia 14/10/2019, tivemos:

- [Convert Files to an universal format, for edit and then Save to orignal format](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415966/5878)
- [VBA code does not want to fetch values in other tab](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415963/5878)
- [How to get API data with JQuery and display it on HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415952/5878)
- [What is the relationship of SonarQube Quality Gate (Reliability, Safety, and Maintenance) notes A, B.C, and D for Java project approval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416012/5878)
- [PLY Lex - Token isn't matching correctly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416015/5878)

Algumas já fechadas, inclusive com motivos que não são o de idioma errado pois observou-se que somente a tradução não salvaria a pergunta.

Será que adicionando um filtro por idioma já não conseguiríamos travar esse tipo de pergunta no site, que só gera ruído até que seja traduzida?

Comment: Sou a favor! Esse filtro consegue ignorar strings em blocos de código? Por exemplo, se tiver `print('Hello World')` mas o texto da pergunta está em português, o filtro pega? Se bem que, aplicando no título e texto já chama a atenção do AP e eliminaria a maioria dos casos :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo É algo a se confirmar, mas eu diria que ele ignora trechos de código e analisa apenas os textos, o que talvez fará pegar citações em inglês ou trechos análogos.

Comment: Mas o filtro impede que a pergunta seja feita ou é só um aviso? Pois há o cuidado adicional de não incluir no filtro os vários termos que costumamos usar em inglês ("threads", "properties", etc), já que o SOen não precisa se preocupar com isso. De qualquer forma, acho válido habilitar isso e ver como se sai...

Comment: Talvez seja mais complicado implementar com o pt-br devido aos vários dialetos que o país tem e as semelhanças com outras línguas (como o espanhol). Fora as palavras que não são "oficias" mas que usamos muito. Mas conconrdo com a ideia, da pra testar

Comment: @Costamilam Mas a ideia é fazer o filtro para identificar termos em inglês.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas então em vez de verificar se não tem os termos em pt-br, vai veirificar apenas o inglês? E se começar a aparecer perguntas em espanhol ou outro idoma qualquer, inutilizaria a funcionalidade (nas perguntas em questão)

Comment: @Costamilam exatamente, mas como não existe demanda para outros idiomas, isso não será um problema.

Comment: @Costamilam Os casos que vejo estão sempre em inglês, não me lembro de ter visto uma pergunta feita em espanhol. De qualquer forma, ter um filtro só pra inglês já deve cobrir a maioria dos casos, e caso surjam em outros idiomas, podemos avaliar se vale a pena adicionar mais filtros (mas na frequência atual em que esses idiomas aparecem - que é próximo de zero - eu diria que ainda não precisa)

Comment: Para além dos possíveis problemas causados por falsos-positivos, interessa também saber com que frequência são feitas perguntas em inglês (ou outras línguas) no SOpt, para se ver se se justifica activar (e provavelmente melhorar) o recurso sequer :)

Comment: @JNat é uma frequência alta, por dia que eu vejo são em média 2 (que eu vejo, não frequento tanto o site), imagino que fechamentos por este motivo e edições feita pelos colaboradores do site para evitar o fechamento seriam uma forma de saber a média por dia, mas mesmo que for algo que aparente pouco a situação é simplesmente evitar que a pessoa se confunda, entenda que as pessoas não postam em inglês aqui porque acham que estão no SOen, elas postam em inglês porque elas não sabem que existe sopt, soen, soru, soes, soja [...]

Comment: @JNat [...] Elas provavelmente leem em portugues os menus e tudo mais, mas elas pensam estar vendo assim pq o site detecta o idioma local (estou dizendo o que provavelmente elas pensam). A 4 anos atrás comecei a perguntar para as pessoas pq elas perguntavam em inglês, e todas respostas foram: "para que todos vejam", ou seja não entendiam que são comunidades não ligadas, isso foi até debate no chat principal (estouro de pilha). A sugestão aqui não é ajudar um "gringo" que caia aqui, é ajudar os nativos pt a evitarem retrabalho, acho a sugestão de um aviso ótima e a SO deveria pensar nisso.

Comment: Isto está se tornando cada vez mais frequente, pois ao procurar por "Stack Overflow" no Google (ou outro buscador), irá aparecer o SOpt como resultado se você está acessando de um IP falante da língua portuguesa, na verdade não posso afirmar em outros países, mas no Brasil aparece o SOpt antes do SOen. Acho que é por isso que muita gente acaba caindo no SOpt diariamente e achando que é o SOen...

Comment: E pior que aparece logo abaixo da URL: "*By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our ...*"

Comment: @JNat Hoje perdi as contas de quantas perguntas apareceram em inglês, teve duas em sequencia, algumas eu tenho traduzido na mão, mas realmente muita coisa poderia ser evitada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Já conversei com o Nicolas, estamos levantando direto do banco em produção todas as perguntas fechadas como fora do idioma deste ano para servir de base para construir a regex. Claro que será bastante afetado por muitas vezes fecharmos por outro motivo direto, mas acho que já será um início suficiente para a maioria dos casos.

Answer (score 8):

## Sugestão 1

**Expressão regular:**

`(^|\W)(to|in|how|the|with|error|of|i|from|using|when|help|can|not|what)(\W|$)`

**Aplicar em:** Título somente

**Mensagem de ajuda:**

> Atenção! Este site é exclusivo para perguntas em **Português**.
>
> Se deseja fazê-la em inglês utilize https://www.stackoverflow.com. Se sua pergunta já está em português é recomendado que revise o título da mesma, pois foram identificados termos em outro idioma. Lembre-se que o título deve ser um breve resumo sobre do que se trata a sua pergunta e, se necessário, veja [Como escolher um bom título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/5878)

Não acho que devemos aplicar ao corpo da pergunta dada a quantidade de perguntas que possuem mensagens de erro em inglês, mesmo a pergunta estando devidamente em português.

Comment: Excelente Woss.

Comment: Olhando um teste no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MVGo5T/3) (Case Insensitive), a maior parte dos problemas de tradução foram capturados.

Comment: Sem olhar as estatísticas, talvez a adição das seguintes palavras possam ser feitas: can, not, what, can't.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Boa ideia. Nesse caso basta o `can`, que já captura o `can't` também.

Comment: @Woss A menos que a pessoa digite `cant`, mas não sei se tem tantos casos assim pra justificar colocar essa opção...

Comment: Acho que no início e fim poderia ser simplesmente `\b`: https://regex101.com/r/Hwn0dL/2 (dependendo da engine de regex, `\b` nem sempre é 100% igual a `\W`, mas acho que no caso de títulos de perguntas não deve fazer tanta diferença)

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim, acabei optando pelo `\W` por ser o que eles usam no SOes e aparentemente funciona.

Answer (score 7):

Conversando com o Nicolas levantamos a relação de todas as perguntas que foram fechadas como em outro idioma nos últimos 365 dias.

> https://gist.github.com/acwoss/ce9545029b1934344e1d9922ab16532f

Na relação consta o título atual na data que foi gerada a lista e inclui perguntas que já foram reabertas após a devida tradução para o português.

Separando as palavras desses títulos e removendo pontuações, gerei a lista de palavras dos títulos:

> https://gist.github.com/acwoss/2d2d61dc016d25aa26ebdf6e6c169994

Analisando as palavras mais frequentes, temos as top 50:

```
[('to', 490),
 ('a', 466),
 ('in', 368),
 ('de', 363),
 ('como', 307),
 ('how', 273),
 ('the', 240),
 ('with', 234),
 ('no', 217),
 ('um', 208),
 ('o', 206),
 ('em', 203),
 ('com', 177),
 ('and', 160),
 ('not', 159),
 ('do', 155),
 ('error', 153),
 ('of', 142),
 ('on', 140),
 ('uma', 132),
 ('i', 127),
 ('para', 125),
 ('c', 109),
 ('from', 106),
 ('não', 106),
 ('is', 105),
 ('using', 100),
 ('python', 98),
 ('e', 93),
 ('erro', 90),
 ('for', 84),
 ('php', 77),
 ('android', 71),
 ('data', 70),
 ('que', 68),
 ('usando', 67),
 ('ao', 64),
 ('java', 62),
 ('an', 59),
 ('app', 58),
 ('can', 56),
 ('or', 56),
 ('array', 55),
 ('da', 55),
 ('this', 53),
 ('get', 52),
 ('as', 48),
 ('file', 48),
 ('when', 46),
 ('use', 44)]
```

Então acredito que podemos gerar uma expressão regular a partir desses termos.

Referências:

1. Script para separar as palavras dos títulos: https://repl.it/@acwoss/ClosedAsNotInPortuguese-words
2. Script para levantar as palavras mais comuns: https://repl.it/@acwoss/ClosedAsNotInPortuguese-most-common-words

Comment: Muitas estão em português, quer dizer que foram editadas e não foram reabertas? Ou podem estar reabertas? Como esta lista csv é gerada? Acho que poderíamos verificar o título sem edit.

Comment: @danieltakeshi "e inclui perguntas que já foram reabertas após a devida tradução para o português"

Comment: O Nicolas fez a consulta direto no banco em produção e gerou este CSV.

Comment: Quanto às em português, basta ignorar os termos claramente em português dos mais comuns e focar naqueles exclusivos ao inglês, como `i`, `to`, `an`, `help`, `error`, `how`, etc

Comment: Pensei na solução de ignorar também, mas estatisticamente estaria "ignorando uma parte do universo" de perguntas em inglês. Talvez seja perfeccionismo de minha parte e com certeza este trabalho de vocês está ótimo.

Comment: Sim, mas a ideia é ter apenas uma base de início para já reduzir os falsos positivos e ir adaptando com o tempo. Não acredito que o conjunto irá se alterar muito considerando ainda mais perguntas (em inglês).

Comment: Acho que precisa ver como fazer com termos que não tem tradução para português (ou que o termo em inglês é muito mais usado), como "thread", "crud", etc... De qualquer forma, já será muito bom ter o filtro em ação :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim, esses termos podem ser removidos do filtro sem problemas, mas termos como "help", "error" acredito que poderiam ser mantidos, pois não vejo situações que eles são realmente necessários no título.

Comment: @Woss Concordo, "help" e "error" não se encaixam na definição "termos que não tem tradução para português"

Comment: Achei curioso "python" aparecer como 28º termo mais comum haha