# Que tal um alerta para edições que adicionam "RESOLVIDO" no título da pergunta?

Tags: novo-recurso

Uma prática muito comum em fóruns é adicionar o texto "RESOLVIDO" no título de um tópico quando este foi finalizado e/ou o problema em questão foi resolvido.

Essa prática parece se estender para o Stack Overflow, mesmo que seja um sistema [diferente dos fóruns](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/5878).

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/341393/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/290185/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/357186/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/326549/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/224186/revisions

Sem entrar no mérito se são perguntas boas ou não. [Lista de perguntas com RESOLVIDO no título](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aresolvido).

Acredito que um filtro para isso não só evitaria de ter edições superficiais nas perguntas, como também ajudaria a orientar os usuários sobre o funcionamento da comunidade. O que proponho é a criação de um filtro que quando reconhecido a adição da palavra "resolvido" no título exiba uma mensagem como

> Evite sinalizar uma pergunta como resolvida alterando o título. Se conseguiu resolver o problema, publique a solução como [resposta da sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878), afinal, se foi útil para você pode ser útil para outros usuários.

Já conversei com o Nicolas ([chat, a quem interessar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50029989#50029989)) sobre a possibilidade de criar este filtro e, aparentemente, não é possível hoje, pois o filtro que existe atualmente, utilizado para [identificar o idioma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/5878), só é ativado na criação da pergunta, não na edição. Será avaliado a possibilidade de aplicar, também, este filtro durante a edição, então já deixo aqui minha sugestão.

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma opção mais simples e que resolveria esse problema. Uma lista de palavras chave que alertasse os mods. Assim nós poderiamos cadastrar o RESOLVIDO e mais o nome de alguns cursos e sites que frequentemente colocam spam no site, e mais uma série de outras coisa relevantes. Eu tenho uma lista que periodicamente aplico na pesquisa por falta desse recurso. Tem até uma lista negra, mas ela é 8 ou 80, já impede o uso em vez de alertar, então não dá para usar para muitas coisas.

Comment: @Bacco Não sei se isso seria interessante "depender" dos moderadores. Não parece ser um problema que demandaria um moderador investir o seu tempo. A própria comunidade consegue controlar isso e um alerta desse tipo poderia reduzir consideravelmente o número de casos. Sobre essa notificação de palavras chaves, o [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) não resolveria? Não sei bem como ele funciona, mas direto ele detecta spam no SOpt.

Comment: eu acho complicado não depender, pois o problema é bem maior que o RESOLVIDO (só não aparece justamente por ficar restrito à pesquisa manual de alguns mods). E se jogar todas as ocorrências na fila de usuários, aí também vai gerar um problema de dar destaque em outros pontos em que não é interessante exposição (o caso do SPAM). Tudo bem que poderiamos ter duas listas, uma que alertasse só mod e outra que fosse para uma nova fila para todos os usuários, creio ser simples de implementar (o RESOLVIDO seria da lista geral), mas tenho um certo ceticismo quanto à rede fazer esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Mt bom levantamento. (não li os comentários anteriores).

Comment: A ideia é boa e a do @Bacco melhor ainda

Comment: sei que já tem um tempo, mas, houve alguma alteração ?