# Perguntas feitas em inglês no stack Português

Tags: suporte, comunidade

Aparentemente para minha pessoa não tem nexo isso mas. Qual a lógica de pergunta em inglês sendo que a comunidade toda fala nativamente PT-BR , isso é um erro?

Não que eu seja contra mas creio que a comunidade deve "Abraçar" o PT-BR, já que é Stackoverflow em português tem, do iniciante ao "Jedi" mestres.

Creio que a pergunta inglês é legal mas pode atrapalhar as pessoas que não sabem inglês, essa é minha opinião mas gostaria de saber outras opiniões sobre o assunto e se devo reportar ou ficar quieto e o que eu devo ler para me tornar um melhor ativista?

Comment: O site é somente em português, então vc pode sinalizar essas perguntas para que sejam fechadas, pois existe inclusive um motivo específico para isso (sinalizar -> deveria ser fechada -> não está em português). Veja também: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052

Comment: Inclusive está em discussão a possibilidade de termos um filtro que notifica o usuário quando for postar em inglês: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/5878

Comment: Fechar? Não deveríamos sei la traduzir? Estamos excluindo a pergunta que pode ajudar uma outra pessoa, só por conta da linguagem que ela criou ? O intuito não é ajudar e fazer a comunidade crescer? Sei que posso estar totalmente errado mas e se essa pergunta ajudasse outras pessoas?
Não encontrei "não está em português"

Comment: Ricardo, [no link que passei](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052) tem uma discussão parecida. Basicamente, imagine que a pergunta está traduzida p/ o português. Ela está [dentro do escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Se não estiver, podemos fechá-la, pois não adianta traduzir (ela seria fechada por ser offtopic). Se estiver, vc pode optar por comentar, dizendo ao usuário que traduza a pergunta. De qq forma, um fechamento não é punição e nem algo definitivo, se a pergunta estiver dentro do escopo ela pode ser reaberta depois que for traduzida...

Comment: Entendi queria pedir paciência to tentando ajudar a comunidade crescer, @hkotsubo é que eu achei que o fechar era remover obrigado a todos por explicar melhor.

Comment: @RicardoLucas Sem problemas, é muito bom que vc esteja disposto a entender como o site funciona (admito que não é fácil). Para entender mais sobre fechamentos, sugiro [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/112052) e [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7471/112052) link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mudei a *tag* da pergunta porque não acho que é questão de debater se o Stack Overflow em Português deve ou não receber perguntas em inglês. Ele não deve, ele foi criado para lidar com o português e isto não está em debate. Então pode ser só um dúvida da própria pessoa sobre o que fazer com isto.

Existe um motivo de fechamento justamente porque a pergunta está em outra língua. È ele que deve ser usado. Como alguns usuários ainda não tem privilégio de votar nisto pode sinalizar e indicar que este motivo de fechamento deveria ser usado.

[image: Motivos de fechamento]

Imagino que seja só isto que possamos fazer. Se quer impedir as pessoas sequer de poder postar algo em outra língua poderia sugerir a forma de fazer isto, até onde entendemos só podemos fechar a pergunta e possivelmente remover em seguida.

Tem um [pedido de novo recurso interessante feito pelo Anderson](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/101).

Lembrando que muitas vezes a pergunta pode ser traduzida por qualquer pessoa e ela entrar no escopo, e se estiver fechada provavelmente deveria ser reaberta.

Só quero lembrar que se puder identificar que a pergunta tem outros problemas, costuma ser melhor fechar por este motivo prioritariamente, afinal mesmo que a pessoa traduza o problema continuará lá, então é um motivo melhor ainda. Não é o fim do mundo fechar por problema de língua neste caso, mas não é o ideal.

Em comentários o AP começa mostrar que deseja debater se deveria ser traduzido, isto não estava claro na pergunta original. De qualquer forma também pode ser só perguntando se deveria fazer isto. E se for só isto acho que já foi respondido antes.