# Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow

Tags: suporte, faq, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

> Tradução e adaptação do debate [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) criado por [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Aqui está uma pequena lista de verificações para fazer após escrever uma pergunta (e para pensar antes de escrever a pergunta):

- Você fez uma [busca no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) antes de fazer a pergunta? <sup>1</sup>
- Você explicou o que já tentou para resolver o seu problema?
- Você escolheu um [título bom e descritivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/69296) para a sua pergunta?
- Você especificou qual linguagem e plataforma está usando, incluindo o número da versão quando relevante?
- Se sua pergunta inclui código, você o escreveu como um programa resumido e simplificado, mas completo ao ponto de reproduzir o erro no computador de quem tentar responder a sua pergunta? <sup>2</sup>
- Se sua pergunta inclui código, você verificou se ele está formatado corretamente? Você sabe como usar [Markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? <sup>3</sup>
- Se o seu código não compila, você incluiu o erro exato do compilador?
- Se sua pergunta não inclui código, tem certeza de que não deveria?
- Se o seu programa lançar uma exceção, você incluiu a exceção com a mensagem e o rastreamento de pilha?
- Se o seu programa produz resultados diferentes dos esperados, você deixou bem claro o que esperava, por que esperava e os resultados atuais?
- Se sua pergunta estiver relacionada a algo específico de um local (idiomas, fusos horários), você forneceu as informações relevantes sobre seu sistema (por exemplo, seu fuso horário atual)?
- Você verificou se sua pergunta parece razoável em termos de formatação?
- Você verificou a ortografia e a gramática da melhor maneira possível? <sup>4</sup>
- Você leu toda a questão para si mesmo com atenção, para ter certeza de que faz sentido e contém informações suficientes para que qualquer um que a leia consiga entendê-la, sem ter qualquer contexto que você já tenha?

Se a resposta a qualquer uma dessas perguntas for "**não**", você deve reservar um tempo para corrigir sua pergunta antes de publicá-la, passando por esta lista. Sei que pode parecer muito esforço, mas ajudará você a obter uma resposta útil o mais rápido possível; e você pode até resolver seu problema sozinho no processo! <sup>5</sup>

Não se esqueça de que você está basicamente pedindo a outras pessoas que o ajudem pela bondade de seus corações - **cabe a você** fazer tudo o que puder para tornar isso o mais simples possível.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Se você passou de "algo que não está funcionando" para "fazendo uma pergunta" em menos de 10 minutos, provavelmente não pesquisou o suficiente. Isso deve incluir coisas como pesquisas normais na web (por exemplo, por uma mensagem de erro que você está recebendo), verificação da documentação, depuração (especialmente para exceções) e pesquisa no próprio Stack Overflow por questões semelhantes.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>O ideal é que qualquer pessoa que responda à pergunta seja capaz de copiar seu código, colá-lo em um editor de texto, compilá-lo, executá-lo e observar o problema. Aplicativos de console são bons para isso - a menos que sua pergunta seja diretamente sobre um aspecto da interface do usuário, prefira escrever um aplicativo de console curto. Remova tudo o que não estiver diretamente relacionado à sua pergunta, mas mantenha-o completo o suficiente para ser executado - um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Tente evitar códigos que fazem os usuários rolar a tela horizontalmente. Talvez você precise mudar a forma como as quebras de linhas são feitas na sua IDE. Reserve um tempo para deixar isso o mais claro possível para aqueles que estão tentando ajudá-lo.</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>Não estamos procurando perfeição - apenas algum esforço. Se você sabe que seu português não é bom ou não conhece muito bem o [jargão profissional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarg%C3%A3o_profissional) de TI, veja se um colega ou amigo pode ajudá-lo com sua pergunta antes de postá-la.</sub>

<sup>5</sup>  <sub>Mais ou menos como descrito em [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos)</sub>

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Todos itens do tópico no post são importantes no geral, mas esse aqui é o problema mais comum do site `Se sua pergunta inclui código, você o escreveu como um programa curto, mas completo?`, acho que dizer apenas "programa curto" nem sempre é claro (entendo que é quase uma tradução), acho que poderia ser o segundo item e talvez melhorado o texto dele.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, e for assim: `Se sua pergunta inclui código, você o escreveu como um fragmento que reproduza o erro?`

Comment: Pois é, esse é meu medo, raramente as pessoas entendem o que é um exemplo minimo, sem as partes desnecessárias e não relacionadas a falha, acho que alguns dos tópicos aqui no post deveria ser links, além de melhorar um pouco para pessoas pouco familiarizadas com certas palavras, até entendo o que é fragmento, no contexto, mas para quem lê de fora pensa q é só tirar um pedaço e colar na pergunta. Vou tentar pensar em um texto curto e simples para esse item do tópico.

Comment: "Saída esperada e saída atual" é algo que agrega muito ao post, é literalmente "uma olhada" e o leitor entende o problema, mas mesmo assim muita gente vacila nisso

Comment: Qual o significa do `*` no item "_Se o seu programa produz resultados diferentes dos esperados, você declarou o que esperava, por que * esperava e os resultados reais?_"? Nesse mesmo item acredito que "atuais" é melhor "reais". @GuilhermeNascimento talvez "simplificado" em vez de "curto"?

Comment: @RafaelTavares não digo sempre, mas algumas vezes só de comparar a saída com o esperado vem a solução de uma vez.

Comment: @Costamilam eu pretendia dividir o tópico e na hora me pareceu uma boa ideia dar atenção a outra coisa e acabei esquecendo o * no meio da frase. Já foi corrigido.

Comment: @Costamilam curto no sentido de mais curto possivel, ainda sim que seja claro, não é bem a questão de ser simples, mas sim a melhor maneira de se explicar esse paragrafo para quem esta começando a "aprender perguntar"

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, parabéns pela iniciativa. Muito boa sua postagem.

Comment: @Solkarped, obrigado. Se tiver alguma sugestão é só editar.

Comment: Uma coisa legal disso é que as pessoas podem ver que o que queremos não é algo inventado pelo SOpt, se no SOen aceitam bagunça é só porque não tem gente ligando mais. Se alguém acha que o Jon Skeet está errado tenho zero respeito pela opinião dessa pessoa.

Comment: uma sugestão pegando um gancho no comentário do @GuilhermeNascimento, podemos incluir ai um link para uma pergunta bem formatda, com codigo no snippet por exemplo? talvez isso ajude a entender o que queremos dizer com "exemplo minimo e verificável"

Comment: @RicardoPontual tem alguma sugestão em mente?

Comment: como o snippet funciona com html/css/javascript, pesquisei as perguntas com mais pontuação com essas tags, as primeiras que aparecem com snippet nas perguntas são essas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81728/57220 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6770/57220, e seguindo a ordem de pontuação, as primeiras que vi com respostas com snippets, que também serviriam como referência foram essas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37313/57220 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2817/57220 qualquer uma delas serviria como referência

Comment: @RicardoPontual não creio que irá resolver, porque as pessoas infelizmente chegam aqui as pressas e ao mesmo tempo "com preguiça", fora que HTML, CSS e JS são apenas alguns casos, temos muitos hibridos que dependem de muita coisa para funcionar bem dentro do StackSnippet, o que torna muito dificil para o usuário, o que a pessoa tem que entender é como fazer uma versão sem toda a parte desnecessária e ainda sim ocorra exatamente o mesmo erro ou funcionamento desejado para que a pergunta se torne compreensivel.